# Entity Framework 6.0 where column value is not null. doesn't work

Tags: c#, lambda, orm, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.  I want to bring back all Distinct values for a given column from a table where one of the column values is not null.  In SQL it would be this:

```
select Distinct(Source) from WorkItem where Source is not null;
```

When I try this in Entity Framework with Lambda expressions, I tried this:

```
return dbContext.WorkItems
    .Where(m => m.Source != null)
    .Select(t => t.Source)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

This doesn't work. It returns Distinct all right, but it's including the Null value, which I don't want. I researched quite a bit, but couldn't really understand how to make this work.  I can work around it in other ways, but it bothers me that I can't figure this one out.  How do you query for columnvalue != null in Entity Framework. Any help Help appreciated.

Comment: It looks correct to me. Have you tried `return dbContext.WorkItems.Select(workItem => workItem.Source).Where(source => source != null).Distinct().ToList();`?

Comment: For me everything is alright. Can you provide us WorkItems model?

Comment: to Rufus:  Tried what you wrote.  Same thing, didn't work.  I got three results, one of which was Null, just like when I did it my original way...

Comment: to Andre:  Any particular part of the model class?  It's a whole bunch of strings and ints and a dates, most of which are not particularly interesting.